# Icono en Allegro

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego con `Allegro 4.2.2` en `Code::Bloks 16.01` y quisiera añadirle un icono personalizado.
Buscando por Internet encontré que añadiéndole un archivo de recurso al proyecto se podía hacer, pero solo logre que el ejecutable `.exe` y la terminal tuvieran el Icono, pero la ventana de Allegro No!.

Encontré que utilizando `windows.h` podía añadirle el icono a la ventana. Pero no se puede cargar `windows.h` y `Allegro` al mismo tiempo, porque chocan. Después encontré [aquí](http://libreallegro.blogspot.com/) que debía cargar `winalleg.h` como remplazo al `windows.h`, aunque no manejo muy bien la API de Windows, seguí buscando y encontré en los siguientes enlaces como hacerlo pero esto no me resulta en allegro
[http:// winprog.org/tutorial/es/resources.html](http://%20winprog.org/tutorial/es/resources.html)
[http:// winprog.org/tutorial/es/menus.html](http://%20winprog.org/tutorial/es/menus.html)

Si uso esto me dice

```
error: 'hInstance' was not declared in this scope
Código

HICON hMyIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAINICON));
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería

**Game.cpp**

```
#include\<allegro.h\>
#include<winalleg.h>

#define V_Ancho 800
#define V_Alto 600

BITMAP *buffer;

int main() {
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    install_mouse();
    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED,V_Ancho,V_Alto,0,0);
    show_mouse(screen);

    buffer = create_bitmap(V_Ancho,V_Alto);
    buffer = load_bitmap("background.bmp",0);

    blit(buffer,screen,0,0,0,0,V_Ancho,V_Alto);

    while(!key[KEY_ESC]){
    readkey;
    }

    destroy_bitmap(buffer);

    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

**resource.rc**

```
#ifndef _resource_rc
#define _resource_rc

MAINICON    ICON    "ICON 32x32.ico"

#endif // _resource_rc
```

Dejo el proyecto en el siguiente enlace:
[https:// goo.gl/qcRcMM](https://%20goo.gl/qcRcMM)

Answer (score 0):

1. Configurar en el toolchain del codeblocks para que el programa encuentre el archivo windres.exe. Es el archivo encargado de crear el exe con la imaje.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Suponiendo que tenemos un icon llamado saitama.ico, la pasta del proyecto deveria quedar así:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. El archivo rc tiene la seguiente linea:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Compilamos el proyecto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y aparecerá la pasta debug o release. En mi caso debug. Depende de como esté configurado el proyecto.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Dentro de la pasta está el exe ya con la imaje como se puede apreciar.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   Eso es todo deberia funcionar.